# Randomly pairing users in Firebase

Tags: firebase, function, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I'm developing an application using Flutter and Firebase and I have to solve a problem that sounds like this:

- each user (at any time) can put himself in a **waiting list**
- Firebase has to handle the waiting list by **creating (randomly) pairs of users**

My idea is to have a collection in the Cloud Firestore for the waiting list in which each user is a document and a **cloud function** that reacts to the document creation by searching for an other user (document) in the collection, deleting both documents (i.e. removing the users from the waiting list) and creating another document in another collection that represents the pair.
The main issue is to design (if possible) a transaction in order to guarantee that two or more executions of the same cloud function do not overlap.
Any suggestion? Or any other way to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, there is either a person in the waiting list, or someone else 'randomly' pairs with that person? Or would there have to be a minimum number of people in the waiting list? I don't think you need to use cloud functions to do this

Comment: As soon as there are (at least) 2 persons in the waiting list, I can pair them. How do you suggest to do this? The users only put theirself in the list. The process of pairing the users must be automated.

Comment: I would say for the code when someone opts to put themselves in the list, "if a document in this collection (waiting-list) exists, then delete it and create another document in this other collection (pairings); otherwise, create a document in the waiting list".

Comment: you could have a field on the user, 'paired: true/false' and add a condition to the query, like waiting-list-collection.where(paired, isEqualTo: false).get(), and instead of deleting the document you could just make updating that field the first step when a 'pairing' is made

Comment: Yeah I also through this. Doing this way how should I perform the query? I think inside the transaction. But also... if the transaction fails (for example because the chosen document was target as paired by another transaction) how Firebase handle this situation?

Comment: I see what you mean about if there are enough transactions happening simultaneously how there could be some overlap between getting a user from the list and pairing with them. Maybe another option would be a way to detect if there had been a double-pairing, and returning the mis-paired user the queue without them really noticing ... maybe someone has a better solution though

Comment: Yeah that's the problem... waiting for someone else though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all the users in a single document with `Unique ID` and data like following:

[image]

Then you could use a **Cloud Function** and that will execute following things:

1. Retrieving the `Array` called *waiting* from a specific document. It
   will add new account `user id` to that array.

   [image]
2. If the `array` has got at least 2 elements. It will add a new
   `array` of `maps` named *paired* from the 2 elements from the *waiting* list and
   add the value to firestore. It will call the existing *paired*
   `array` and add the new 2 elements and save it to `Firestore`. Also update the *paired_with* field in
   users doc.
3. It will remove the 2 elements from waiting list update an empty
   list.

Comment: I have created more complex things. If you have doubt please ask.

Comment: Thanks! My doubt is... since I keep all the pairing system in a document, is this solutions scalable? If I have enough transactions happening simultaneously, one of them will success and the others will continue to fail?

Comment: Actually if you use cloud function trigger the waiting list will have never more than 2 elements. Because when it's get at least 2 elements it will create the pair and save a new empty list. As if you are saving a paired_with field in  each users document you don't need paired array actually. It's as a backup. So, no problem. Make sure a single document is less than 1mb. You will have never exceeded 200kb believe me.

Comment: Also Cloud functions are built in asynchronous. So, it will do all the things one by one no matter how many users are pairing at the same time.

Comment: Doing this way...

`const newUser:String = snap.data().name;`

`let ref = firestore.collection('pairing_system').doc('data');`

`await ref.update({  waiting: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(newUser)  });`

... I insert the new users into the array.
How can I get the actual lenght and extract a pair of user from the array?

Comment: You need to use a cloud function to do thing async. The function will be triggered every time a firestore document created on the users collection. Then you will get the id of newly created user. Then you will call the waiting list array and add the new user id. Now you will create the pair from the array by iterating using for loop and save the pair as 2 new variables. Then call the paired array from firestore and add the 2 pairs and update. Also remove the pairs from the waiting list.

Comment: Yeah I got this. Do I need to do all the process of pairing inside the foreach loop by taking the 2 users (if there are) and pair it or there is a smart way to do that (for example by directly getting the length of the array or its content)? Also, since I can't parallelize this work, will the performance be a problem? I talked about users, but they can actually be requests or something similar... Let's say I could have some thousands of users/requests per second

Comment: I told you no problem. Cloud function is super fast and built in asynchronous. You can create the pair by using other methods like by picking 2 random elements from the array.

Comment: If It worked. Please set it as correct answer. It would be helpful for others.

Comment: Sorry I had a busy day. I've just implemented your solution and it works great! Really thank you :)

Comment: Thanks. Never forget to upvote the correct answer.